# How to pass two arguments to an onchange handler in a select tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the `category.id` and the `category.companyName` to be passed to my onCategoryChange...

But if I pass an array or object, they get stringified...?

```
<select required onChange={onCategoryChange} className="mb4" id="category">
    {categories.map((category, i) => (
      <option key={i} value={category.id}>{category.categoryName}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

```
  const onCategoryChange = (e) => {
   into a string
    setSelectedCategory(e.target.id)
    handleSetFormData([e.target.value.categoryName, e.target.id])
  }
```

Right now if I pass the whole category object like `<option key={i} value={category}>{category.categoryName}</option>`

on the it gets converted to a string.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: if you're using native select, I think you're on the right track. Just pass the id and somewhere you have a categories object to reference to, like `categories[index].categoryName` , of course your categories should be an object to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to approach this (in my opinion)

1 - creating a mapping based on the category ID, something like

```
const categoryNames = {
  id1: 'Category Name 1',
  id2: 'Category Name 2'
  ...etc
}

onCategoryChange = e => {
  const categoryId = e.target.value;
  const categoryName = categoryNames[categoryId];
  ...
}
```

Or 2, pass in the category name as `data-category-name`

```
<option data-category-name={category.name} value={category.id} ... />

onCategoryChange = e => {
  const categoryName = e.target.data-category-name;
  const categoryId = e.target.value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: e.target.data-category-name does not exist... e.target is the select... but value comes from the option... ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but I don't know if its good or bad performance wise. basically the idea is to `stringify` the object and then `parse` it again.

```
<select required onChange={onCategoryChange} className="mb4" id="category">
    {categories.map((category, i) => (
      <option key={i} value={JSON.stringify(category)}>{category.categoryName}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

```
const onCategoryChange = (e) => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    setSelectedCategory(obj.id)
    handleSetFormData([obj.categoryName, obj.id])
  }
```

You can also try this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rzvdsp)